# DRYing controllers with directives vs. service

Tags: angularjs

The app i'm building has multiple views, each with its own controller. All my controllers start in the same way and differ in one methods;

```
$scope.a = ...              // same for all controllers
$scope.b = ...              // same for all controllers
$scope.c = function(){...}  // same for all controllers

$scope.d = function(){...}  // is different for each controller
```

They say keep your controllers thin and factorise them with services. 
But if I put a, b, c in a service they will be shared among all controllers, wherease I want each controller to keep its own a, b, c in its own scope. *I'm not trying to share data, just the code.*

So I created a directive that references the parent scope and declares the common stuff in its own controller. It solves my problem but is there a best practice you could recommend?

Comment: Sounds like your code is stateful  It's probably best for the service code to be stateless and thus shareable across multiple controllers while the data is left inside the controller itself (unless there is a need to have the data shared across multiple controllers such as master data that doesn't change too much).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define controller methods as scope properties, then you can use simple mixin approach to extend each of the scope objects with common methods.

Say you define an object with reusable methods:

```
var mixin = {
    a: function() { return this.name; },
    b: function() {},
    c: function() {}
};
```

and then when you need those methods you simply mix them into current `$scope`:

```
app.controller('Controller1', function($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'One';

    // Create common methods
    angular.extend($scope, mixin);

    // Define unique method
    $scope.d = function() {};
});
```

Inside mixin methods `this` will point to individual `$scope` object.

Below is a demonstration of the approach.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Vc00GsRTi5d6VNcILsva?p=preview

Comment: it's a nice approach, could you say how it's better/worse than using a directive?

Comment: To me using directive for this type of functionality is not right. This is more architectural pattern problem, rather than specific tool problem. So using directive is a not ideal to me, plus it's extra overhead from using Angular directive just to define methods. This is really classical inheritance problem but in Angular field. So you have many possibilities how to extend one class with base. In this case I used mixins, but you could also use prototypical inheritance, or borrow constructors, or even composition pattern. But to me mixin is the simples and optimal.